# How can I loop Swift 5 array indices offset to certain number using ForEach in view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

How can I loop an array using ForEach offset to a number

I have an array cities with a size of 10, how can I loop using this array 15 times?

```
ForEach(cities.indices, id: \.self) { index in
}
```

I am looking for a way to increment by +5 or any Int

I am initialising an array of cities size and adding the offset, thought there is a cleaner solution using indices but I cant find anything on the documentation

Comment: What is supposed to happen after you have reached the end of the array (index == 10)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
ForEach(0..<cities.count + 5, id:\.self) { index in
let city = cities[index]
}
```

Be careful. The loop will crash if it tries to access the index out of reach.

Comment: This will always crash, won't it?

Comment: Yes, it will, if he accesses the city, but maybe he just needs that pointer to display something else. It can be done with simple if else statement